# What is the best way to check a 3g router is up and running?

Tags: linux, networking, 3g-network

I have a situation where I need to write an application to monitor that a 3g router is up and running, as sometimes the 3g connection isn't stable.  I have to ensure the bandwidth usage doesn't go over the limit.

I am not sure what is the best way to monitor the 3g connection status with the minimum usage of the bandwidth of the 3g connection. Any good suggestion?

Comment: Please clarify the question.  What does "up and running" mean?  Do you want to monitor how much data is passing to and fro between a 3G modem and the computer?  Or do you want to monitor when the modem is connected to the network?  And are you talking about a router or a modem?

Comment: Hello, sorry for not explain clearly. I have a server (Linux Centos), there's an application will connect to a client application via the 3g router. And i have to write another application on the server side, to monitor the 3g router connection status and if i fail to connect to the 3g router, i'll have notify another application connect to another 3g router which is available. does it make sense? If i able to monitor the data has been passing through, that would be great. It's a 3g router using Orange SIM card. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ping is not blocked, you can simply do `ping -c 10 8.8.8.8 | grep -oE "[0-9]* received" | sed "s/ received//g"`. If the connection is up, you should get nonzero (>7 for any reasonably good connection) value.

Answer (score 0):

Any reasonable quality router should have an SNMP service which can be polled to check the status of each interface, and the amount of traffic over each interface.

If your router has this, it's pretty trivial to write what you need in a variety of scripting languages.  I've used the Perl [`Net::SNMP`](http://search.cpan.org/~dtown/Net-SNMP-v6.0.1/) library for this sort of stuff in the past.